# How to find start and end coordinate of line segment on binary image under MATLab?

Tags: matlab, line, polynomials

I am using MATLab to extract boundaries on raster image. While the process I have got braked line along my wanted boundary. I want to join those line. I require your help. Thank You.
code as follows

```
x=imread('1_s.tif');%open orthoimage%

x1=uint8((1/3)*(double(x(:,:,1))+double(x(:,:,2))+double(x(:,:,3))));%create gray scale image%

a=im2bw(x1,0.501);
imshow(a);
b=bwareaopen(a,40);
imshow(b);
se=strel('line' ,1,90);
c=imerode(b,se);
figure,imshow(c);

[L]= bwlabel(c);

 s=regionprops(L,'Centroid','Eccentricity');
 centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
 xc=find([s.Eccentricity]>0.979);
  qq=ismember(L,xc);
   imshow(qq);
```

Comment: Please do no post code in the comment, it looks sloppy, edit your question and enter the code in the question.

Comment: could you upload the image?